# Why does this function cause memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glib

I'm playing around with `libfprint` and I created a really simple function:

```c
#include <libfprint-2/fprint.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib-unix.h>

void start_device() {
    FpContext *ctx = fp_context_new();
    fp_context_enumerate(ctx);
}

int main() {
    start_device();
}
```

I'm compiling with gcc using `gcc -fsanitize=address` and I'm getting memory leaks and I can't figure out why.

Edit: Output

```
=================================================================
==55025==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 3 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f14a8aba6af in __interceptor_malloc (/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xba6af)
    #1 0x7f14a56d3017 in __vasprintf_internal (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x80017)
    #2 0x7af10c9e9cbbccff  (<unknown module>)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 3 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Edit 2: If I delete `fp_context_enumerate(ctx);` I don't get memory leaks, so I guess there's the problem but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That function](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-dev/FpContext.html#fp-context-new) is tagged with the `transfer full` label, meaning it's transferring full responsibility to the caller for the pointer. See [here](https://foldoc.org/transfer%20full) for more detail.

That means you're responsible for freeing it when you're done. And, by freeing, I *don't* mean the normal C `free` function. The returned pointer is a `GObject` one, so you should simply `g_object_unref` it and let the object reference counting framework take care of the actual freeing.

In other words, something like:

```c
include <libfprint-2/fprint.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib-unix.h>

FpContext *start_device() {
    FpContext *ctx = fp_context_new();
    fp_context_enumerate(ctx);
    return ctx;
}

void stop_device(FpContext *ctx) {
    g_object_unref(ctx);
}

int main() {
    FpContext *ctx = start_device();

    // Work your magic.

    stop_device(ctx);
}
```

---

But keep in mind that un-freed memory and memory leaks aren't quite *necessarily* the same thing (or even a bad thing), it's just when they add up over time that they cause issues.

For example, startup code may leak memory that it never cleans up, such as if a 4K buffer is created once for `printf` purposes the first time it's called. It may well rely on process exit to "free" that memory.

Obviously, this allocation won't be a real problem because it's not allocating 4K continuously, just once at the start. In that sense, it's no more serious than having a stack allocated for your process :-)

In fact, based on your edit:

> If I delete `fp_context_enumerate(ctx);`, I don't get memory leaks so I guess there's the problem but I don't know why.

That's exactly what I was stating above (confirmed by the [source code](https://github.com/freedesktop/libfprint/blob/master/libfprint/fp-context.c)). Enumerating with `fp_context_enumerate()` will, the first time it's called for a context, allocate some memory to detect and store details on each fingerprint scanning device, and that memory is subsequently kept around.

Then a call to `fp_context_get_devices()` will first call `fp_enumerate()` (which returns immediately if already done for that context), then return a pointer to internal data set up during enumeration <sup>(1)</sup>.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> That's why it's a `transfer none` operation, it just gives you a pointer to internal data. Because that data is never actually freed within the process, there's no reference counting needed for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm still getting leaks tho, output on my question edit